# Does Gentoo Hardened use -fstack-protector-strong?

Tags: gentoo, gcc

I'm trying to build a fairly hardened Gentoo install and I'd like to at least make sure that everything is built with `-fstack-protector-strong` if not `-fstack-protector-all`.

I'm on the `hardened/linux/amd64/selinux` profile, and here's my make.conf:

```
CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
CXXFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
USE="bindist mmx sse sse2 systemd -consolekit"
PORTDIR="/usr/portage"
DISTDIR="${PORTDIR}/distfiles"
PKGDIR="${PORTDIR}/packages"
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="~amd64"
```

Does Hardened automatically set `-fstack-protector-strong`, or do I need to pass that to `CFLAGS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Gentoo Hardened uses `fstack-protector-all` by default, so you do not need to pass `CFLAGS` yourself to enable stack smashing protection. The default `CFLAGS` for the Hardened profile include:

```
CFLAGS="-fPIE -fstack-protector-all -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro"
```

See [this section](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/FAQ#Do_I_need_to_pass_any_flags_to_LDFLAGS.2FCFLAGS_in_order_to_turn_on_hardened_building.3F) from the Gentoo Hardened FAQ for more info.